# Find the derivative of each of the the following functions

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the derivative of each of the the following functions.

1. $f(x)=\sqrt{7+\sqrt{x^3}}$

$\frac{d}{du}\left(\sqrt{u}\right)\frac{d}{dx}\left(7+\sqrt{x^3}\right)$

A: $3x^2/4\sqrt{x^3}\sqrt{\sqrt{x^3}+7}$

2. $7x/\sqrt{5-2x}$

$7\frac{\frac{d}{dx}\left(x\right)\sqrt{5-2x}-\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sqrt{5-2x}\right)x}{\left(\sqrt{5-2x}\right)^2}$

A: $7(-x+5)/(-2x+5)$

Are my solutions correct?

Comment: ok, please also show a few steps how you apply chain rule and quotient rule, so we know you are not purely guessing.

Comment: i used chain for the first and quotient for the second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is correct.

The second should be $7\frac{5-x}{(5-2x)^{3/2}}$.

You'll most likely spot the mistake yourself, but here's a hint anyways:
$$\frac{A+\frac{x}{A}}{A^2}=\frac{\frac{A^2+x}{A}}{A^2}=\frac{A^2+x}{A^3}$$